# grep for a string in multiple files under tar and print wc -l

Tags: grep, tar, wc

I am looking for a command / script that can search for the given string in multiple files under a given tar.gz file and give the wc -l of the string along with specific file name.

I tried the below but doesn't give me any output.

```
tar -zxf /home/myname/April/maillogs.tar.gz
for f in /home/myname/April/*; do
  grep -l "sent" $f |wc -l
done
```

Comment: Check out zgrep utility

Comment: That is not correct: zgrep will not show the filename of the matching files in the archive as the OP needs specific filenames that match "sent" with the count. You need a script or a better grep tool, e.g. [ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep).

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in comments you can do it in a single `zgrep` command:

```
zgrep -c "sent" /home/myname/April/*.tar.gz
```

From `grep` manual:

> -c, --count
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I checked this but my situation is like below. Lets say I have 5 files (file1, file2 .. ) I am looking for number of "sent" pattern in all those 5 files under tar.gz file and list the counts along with file names. Please help..

Comment: @Ram What's the output you get with the command from my answer?

Comment: I get the total number of occurrence for the given string cumulatively from all the 5 files inside the tar.gz.

Comment: Hi All, 
I am looking for total number of "string" occurrence from each file individually. This will help me save a lot of time in my report preparation.
Please help me to find a way to achieve this.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @Ram Update your question with the output you get with the command from my answer.

Comment: Lets say I have a zip file "mail_logs.020417.tar.gz" and this has 7 files inside namely (mailog.Mon, Maillog.Tue, Maillog.Wed.........Maillog.Sun). I need to grep for a word "sent" in each of the files inside the tar.gz and need an output of total number of occurrence of "sent" in each file along the file name. 
For example: I need an output as below :
Maillog.Mon : 1234
Maillog.Tue : 2345
Maillog.Wed : 3456 and so on.

I used the below code as you gave and below is the output I got 

`[root@servername]# zgrep -a sent mail_logs.020417.tar.gz |wc -l
1925677
[root@servername]#
`

Comment: Hi All, I am Still stuck up in this requirement. Please help to achieve the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: -c option is also giving me the total count. I am looking for the count from each individual files inside the tar.gz file.. Please let me know the possibilities to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) with options `-z -c`:

```
ugrep -z -c "sent" /home/myname/April/*.tar.gz
```

This reports the tar.gz "sent" matches in a logical way by listing the tar.gz files with their {path/file} parts:

```
foo.tar.gz{path/file1.txt}:123
foo.tar.gz{path/file2.txt}:456
...
bar.tar.gz{path/file1.txt}:789
bar.tar.gz{path/file2.txt}:0
...
```